# Sorting stacked barplots in r-plotly

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-plotly, stacked-chart

I have some stacked bar plots, that I created with r-plotly, and now I would like to reorder the bars.
Each bar represents a different sample and the stacks are the different taxonomies found in the samples.
I would like to reorder my bar plots by the abundance of a specific taxonomy.

How can I do that in r-plotly?

Comment: If you are using `ggplot` from plotting the graphs, I can suggest a method!!

Comment: @ashwinagrawal Yes, I am using ggplot!

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).